# Hibernate @Column annotation cannot mapping to database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Entity in Spring Boot and PostgreSql, I'm using @Column annotation to mapping to database. This is my Entity snip code :

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12355345L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userid;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private Integer username;
```

When id run and test with postman, i get an error :

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>
> ```
>  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column users0_.usersid does not exist
>   Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "users0_.user_id".
> ```

I don't know why. How to resolve this ?

Comment: `@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")` in this line is `users`  your table?means name is right? and no need to add name in `@entity`

Comment: Show us the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things for your info.

1) Need to check your `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property as depends on that property, the database tables, columns will be populated by Hibernate.

2) Next drop the existing table and change the value as  `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` so that it will create/update table according to the annotations provided in the entity class

3) Remove unnecessary annotations. Following is enough.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "user_id")
 private String userid;

 ................
```

Comment: OMG . i'm sorry , it's my fault :( . I'm mistake lib when import @column annotation beetwen javax.persistence.Column and javax.jdo.annotations.Column . Tks for help, so sorry.